# convert list of strings to dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to convert a string representation of a dictionary where the keys aren't encapsulated in double quotes e.g.

```
'{output:{OUTPUT_PATH:hdfs://x.x.x.x:X/tmp/x/x,OUTPUT_TYPE:hdfs},''input:{INPUT_TEMPTABLE:sample,INPUT_TYPE:hdfs,INPUT_PATH:hdfs://x.x.x.x:X/sparkStream/sample1/},''process:{query.param:${http.query.param.name},PROCESS_SQL:1,PROCESS_TYPE:sql},''attributes:{path:./,restlistener.remote.source.host:127.0.0.1,filename:1211999192960535,restlistener.remote.user.dn:none,uuid:2b025f49-7d53-49db-8063-24ddda29fc4a}}'
```

into a dictionary like:

```
{"output":{"OUTPUT_PATH":"hdfs://x.x.x.x:X/tmp/x/x","OUTPUT_TYPE":"hdfs"},"input":{"INPUT_TEMPTABLE":"sample","INPUT_TYPE":"hdfs","INPUT_PATH":"hdfs://x.x.x.x:X/sparkStream/sample1/"},"process":{"query.param":"${http.query.param.name}","PROCESS_SQL":"1","PROCESS_TYPE":"sql"},"attributes":{"path":"./","restlistener.remote.source.host":"127.0.0.1","filename":"1211999192960535","restlistener.remote.user.dn":"none","uuid":"2b025f49-7d53-49db-8063-24ddda29fc4a"}}
```

The data can't be pickled or converted into a serialized format like JSON because it is coming from another process in the current format.

Comment: How did you get that string in the first place? That doesn't look like any commonly supported format.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo the formatting is pretty different. I think this is more of an issue of needing to use pickle or json or yaml.

Comment: Are those strings actually all joined together or are the commas supposed to be between them?

Comment: @Ravi Kiran, Can you give us some information on where this is being passed into the list from? My intuition is saying that you are trying to pass a dictionary through a socket or subprocess or something, and if that's the case you might be better off pickling or serializing the data with some method like JSON/YAML/XML

Comment: I reckon this is something generated by OP. They'd be better off learning about JSON perhaps?

Comment: Hi deceze and GrantWilliams , i am getting this kind of a format from a custom processor in Nifi. I need to parse this and extract the necessary keys and values from it.

Comment: @RaviKiran, are you able to convert the output from Nifi to a standard format like JSON? Or is it something out of your control?

Comment: @GrantWilliams i am sorry currently it out of my control.Need to somehow parse this.

Comment: @RaviKiran I guess that means your best bet is to import re, use re.split() on the "{, }, :" characters and add double quotes to each tokenized string that isn't a blank space e.g. '' or ' ' then call an eval() function on top of that (now valid) string representation of the dictionary. It's going to be pretty hacky, but i dont know if you have a lot of other choices.

Comment: @GrantWilliams Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will try to implement it.

Comment: @deceze, i believe i edited the question to better represent the question being asked (after being clarified in the comments), and can be taken off hold so that a solution can be given

Comment: @GrantWilliams Given that this seems invalid even as a string literal (weird `''`) and the format is vaguely specified at best I am skeptical how far this can be answered, but suit yourself. :)

Comment: @deceze i think the problem is that it doesnt have double quotes around the keys. so im pretty sure you can split on {, }, and : then add double quotes, then evaluate it. but we'll see when im finished testing. might not be as easy as i hoped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `re`, which is probably more efficient, and with some assumptions:

- the string always start with `'{` and ends with `}'`
- top level elements are separated by `,''` and no other `,''` in the data
- sublevel elements are separated by `,` and no other `,` in the data

then this can be done like this:

```
ms = "'{output:{OUTPUT_PATH:hdfs://x.x.x.x:X/tmp/x/x,OUTPUT_TYPE:hdfs},''input:{INPUT_TEMPTABLE:sample,INPUT_TYPE:hdfs,INPUT_PATH:hdfs://x.x.x.x:X/sparkStream/sample1/},''process:{query.param:${http.query.param.name},PROCESS_SQL:1,PROCESS_TYPE:sql},''attributes:{path:./,restlistener.remote.source.host:127.0.0.1,filename:1211999192960535,restlistener.remote.user.dn:none,uuid:2b025f49-7d53-49db-8063-24ddda29fc4a}}'"
result = {}
# get rid of '{ and '}
# split on ,''
for e in ms[2:-2].split(",''"):
    # e is top level
    # split on {
    # e[0] is toplevel key
    # e[1] is sublevel
    e = e.split('{',1)
    # p is sublevel
    # if multiple sublevels split on ,
    p = e[1].split(',') if ',' in e[1] else [e[1]]
    i_dict = {}
    for v in p:
        # for each value in p get rid of trailing }
        v = v.rstrip('}')
        # split the value
        # i[0] is sublevel key
        # i[1] is sublevel value
        i = v.split(':',1)
        #add to sublevel dict
        i_dict[i[0]] = i[1]
    #add sublevel dict as value for toplevel
    result[e[0][:-1]] = i_dict
print(result)
```

output is a dictionary:

```
{'output': {'OUTPUT_PATH': 'hdfs://x.x.x.x:X/tmp/x/x', 'OUTPUT_TYPE': 'hdfs'}, 'input': {'INPUT_TEMPTABLE': 'sample', 'INPUT_TYPE': 'hdfs', 'INPUT_PATH': 'hdfs://x.x.x.x:X/sparkStream/sample1/'}, 'process': {'query.param': '${http.query.param.name', 'PROCESS_SQL': '1', 'PROCESS_TYPE': 'sql'}, 'attributes': {'path': './', 'restlistener.remote.source.host': '127.0.0.1', 'filename': '1211999192960535', 'restlistener.remote.user.dn': 'none', 'uuid': '2b025f49-7d53-49db-8063-24ddda29fc4a'}}
```

with the absence of other input strings, this code is not further tested, YMMV.